# BoundsError: attempt to access Float64 at index [false]

Tags: julia

I'm trying to use Julia to solve an ODE with the code below:

```
using DifferentialEquations

const C = 1.1;
const R = 0.9;
const A = 1e-4;
const B = 60/72;

function flow(t)
    bloodflow = A*sin.(2*π*t/B)
    bloodflow[bloodflow.<0] .= 0;
    return bloodflow
end

function pressure(P,p,t)
    return flow(t)/C - P/(C*R)
end

P0 = 90;
tspan = (0,1);
prob = ODEProblem(pressure,P0,tspan)
sol = solve(prob);
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
BoundsError: attempt to access Float64 at index [false]
```

with a very long Stacktrace.

I'm new to Julia and am still figuring stuff out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define

```
flow(t) = max(0, A*sin(2*π*t/B))
```

The `0` will be promoted to the appropriate float type.

Answer (score 0):

`bloodflow` here

```
bloodflow = A*sin.(2*π*t/B)
```

is a scalar, so you probably want to do:

```
function flow(t)
    bloodflow = A*sin(2π*t/B)
    return bloodflow < 0.0 ? 0.0 : bloodflow
end
```

for the `flow` function.

Comment: If `bloodflow` is a scalar, why use broadcasting?

Comment: I guess you were referring to the `sin.(` call that was in the code? That was a remnant from the code in the qn, I've edited to remove it now.